# Calling a struct instance into a class? (Swift)

Tags: swift, class, struct

I have an instance in a struct that I would like to access in a class, is this at all possible? The struct is not inside the class.

Struct:

```
struct A {
 var x: String = "Text"
}
```

Class:

```
class B{
 //is there a way to call var x here?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible...but... `B` needs to know about `A` somehow. In this regard `Struct`s are no different than what you would do in other languages.

One way of solving this could be to have a reference to `A` in `B` like so

```
class B {
    let a: A = A()

    // now you can get access to x like so: a.x
}
```

If you want to future proof you code a little you could pass the reference to `A` as a parameter to the `init` of `B` like so

```
class B {
    let a: A

    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
    }

    // now you can get access to x like so: a.x
}
```

That way you are free to use different variants of `A` in different scenarios (normal mode vs test for instance). If you hear people talking about "dependency injection" this is basically what they mean.

If you want to hide the implementation details about `x` (the fact that it belongs to `A`) from consumers of `B` you can expose `x` as a readonly `var` on `B`

```
class B {
    let a: A

    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
    }

    var x: String {
        a.x
    }
}
```

The above should get you started I hope :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. But what is your purpose?

```swift
struct A {
    var x: String = "Text"
}

class B {
    let structA: A
    
    init(input: A) {
        self.structA = input
    }
}

let b = B(input: A())
print(b.structA.x)
```

Comment: I just have a function in a class that needs the data from an instance stored in the structure to work properly. Thanks for your help!